# Mockito not mocking method from my mocked custom class [Kotlin - Android]

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, androidx

So I have a very simple class with three public methods. On calls the other which returns a `Boolean`. The class looks like this:

```
open class DataManager(var context: Context) {

    fun startDataManager(){
        if(checkFileExists()){
            startTask()
        }
    }

    fun checkFileExists(): Boolean {
        val mFile: File = context.getDatabasePath("FILE_NAME")
        return mFile.exists()
    }

    fun startTask(){
        //TODO Task here
    }
}
```

So the point here is to check if the method `checkFileExists` is called when I call the `startDataManager` method from outside. This is how I've tried to mock everything:

```
@Test
fun checkFileExists_onDataManagerStart(){
    val dataManagerMock = mock(DataManager::class.java)
    `when`(dataManagerMock.checkFileExists()).thenReturn(true)

    dataManagerMock.startDataManager()

    verify(dataManagerMock, times(1)).checkFileExists()
}
```

So when I run this test, I receive an error about the `context` inside the `checkFileExists()` method is `null` and it cannot check if the real file exists.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at
.data.DataManager.checkFileExists(DataManager.kt:20)
```

As far as my understanding of Mockito goes, when I mock my class, it also should mock the methods. Then, I force a `return true` for the method I want to test, so when I call it it should not run the real code in that method. **Is that right?** What am I missing there?

If it is possible, I would prefer not to use any other library (wrapper) for Mockito. I have some limitations on library usage.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you want to test a class you do not `mock` it. If you need to replace a method within a class, the usual suggestion would be to refactor your code. If you can't do that consider using a `spy`.

Comment: If you create a `mock`, all methods default to do nothing and if they have to return something, then it returns the usual default value of the related class (`null` or their primitive counterpart).

Comment: Are you sure you're using Mockito's `mock` :)?

Comment: @second that's what I am trying to say. But it is not working as expected. As you can see en my code, when I call `startDataManager` it should also call `checkFileExists` with a return of `true`, but instead it fails with `null context` or `file does not exist`

Comment: @r2rek yes sir, I double checked and also changet to `Mockito.mock(...` but the result is the same. I'm using Mockito version 3.1.0

Comment: Oh, ok. Unfortunately can't help you - I moved to mockk because of Mockito's issues with mocking classes.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is your DataManager class require android Context and Mockito have a problems to mock it (in spite of it looks like it should). According to 5th SOLID's principle, create interface with name DataManager with methods

```
fun startDataManager()
fun checkFileExists(): Boolean 
fun startTask()
```

Implement it in some class and replace realisation by abstraction.

With this you can mock and use it easily.

Hope it'll help.